# Update model each time a view is generated in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update my an instance of Post model each time a view PostDetail is generated. So far I've tried multiple approaches but none of them worked. I know that there is ready solution (django-hitcounter) but I would like to write one myself so I can understand what is happening.

The goal there is to add 1 to post.views each time user accesses PostDetail view.

```
models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
```

```
views.py

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've got to the point where Django can return a response (eg: it's found the `Post` object successfully etc...) - you can increment your view count for the object then and proceed to returning the response, so if you change your view to be:

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        self.object.views += 1
        self.object.save()
        return super().render_to_response(context, **kwargs)
```